# Geoloaction acess denied pop-up showing even after permission granted in browser in Ar.js

Tags: geolocation, gps, android-webview, aframe, ar.js

I am trying to use Ar.js with in android webview and after giving both location and camera permissions, I am getting a dialog box saying unable to access geolocation [![like this][1]][1].

When this dialog box appears, then in the log I get a error saying `ERROR(1): User denied Geolocation`. Here is the complete log:

```
07-05 13:33:46.355 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The connection used to load resources from used TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1, which are deprecated and will be disabled in the future. Once disabled, users will be prevented from loading these resources. The server should enable TLS 1.2 or later. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5654791610957824 for more information.", source: 
07-05 13:33:47.176 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(140)] "No DPDB device match.", source: https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js (140)
07-05 13:33:47.176 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(140)] "Failed to recalculate device parameters.", source: https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js (140)
07-05 13:33:47.183 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(140)] "Using fallback Android device measurements.", source: https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js (140)
07-05 13:33:47.399 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(259)] "document.registerElement is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use window.customElements.define instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4642138092470272 for more details.", source: https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js (259)
07-05 13:33:47.520 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(353)] "A-Frame Version: 0.9.2 (Date 2019-05-06, Commit #f57a1fa)", source: https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js (353)
07-05 13:33:47.520 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(353)] "three Version (https://github.com/supermedium/three.js):", source: https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js (353)
07-05 13:33:47.521 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(353)] "WebVR Polyfill Version:", source: https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js (353)
07-05 13:33:47.806 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(140)] "No DPDB device match.", source: https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js (140)
07-05 13:33:47.807 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(140)] "Failed to recalculate device parameters.", source: https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js (140)
07-05 13:33:48.429 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(95)] "THREE.WebGLRenderer", source: https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js (95)
07-05 13:33:49.551 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(4120)] "ERROR(1): User denied Geolocation", source: https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js (4120)
07-05 13:33:53.448 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2612)] "AR.js", source: https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js (2612)
07-05 13:33:54.930 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "[warning] *** Camera Parameter resized from 640, 480. ***", source: https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js (2)
07-05 13:33:55.161 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "[info] Allocated videoFrameSize 307200", source: https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js (2)
07-05 13:33:55.175 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "[info] Pattern detection mode set to 1.", source: https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js (2)
07-05 13:33:55.189 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "[info] Pattern ratio size set to 0.500000.", source: https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js (2)
07-05 13:33:55.189 32209-32209/com.example.sample I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "[info] Labeling mode set to 1", source: https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js (2)
```

I have checked the location permission in android chrome and the location permission is active there.

After this pop up, I get another pop up (even though I am using Android) as [![this][2]][2]

I am having trouble placing the sphere components of A-frame due to this and this is also serving as a starting trouble with Ar.js. Please help me out here.

Comment: Device orientation indeed needs different permissions, I think you should try to use latest A-Frame version (1.0.4) that includes an authorization popup for this matter.

Comment: @StéphaneAlbanese for the reply, but even after using A-Frame version (1.0.4) and the link here https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/device-orientation-permission-ui.html The problem still persists, in fact adding `device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: true"` didn't do anything

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question so that it can help anyone having the same problem in future.

The culprit was using the setWebChromeClient() twice at different places as shown below.

```
   webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            final String[] requestedResources;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                requestedResources = request.getResources();
                for (String r : requestedResources) {
                    if (r.equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE)) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE});
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });


}
```

changed it to a single setWebChromeClient() (like the following) and the first pop up vanished. The second pop-up only appears once now on installation of the app and does not pose any problem as such till now.(if it does in future, I will update the answer).

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                final String[] requestedResources;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    requestedResources = request.getResources();
                    for (String r : requestedResources) {
                        if (r.equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE)) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE});
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });


    }
```